# How to use CMIP6 to predict windspeed in the future?

Tags: meteorology, wind, weather-forecasting, atmosphere-modelling, energy

I'm very new to climate modelling and forecasting, I have chosen a project to forecast wind energy output in the future using wind speed prediction, I wish to use CMIP6 to predict. But I have very little knowledge on how it works, or how to use the model. Can anyone help me get started?

Comment: Based on your question it is hard to answer. What is future? Tomorrow? 100 years from now? CMIP6 is not a model. What are your assumptions for energy output? Do you want to do calculations based on wind turbines that are installed today?

Comment: By future I mean 5 years in the future. Yes I would like to do calculations based on data available in the present